# Cocos2d-x CCLabelTTF does not work on iPad

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I made a `CCLabelTTF` object in one of my custom layers.

```
myLabel = CCLabelTTF::create( "Something", CCSizeMake( 300, 96 ), kCCTextAlignmentCenter, "Arial Rounded MT Bold", 48.0f );
```

Works perfectly fine in the simulator and an iPhone device. But on the iPad, it doesn't work. I've added the font in the resources folder and in the `Info.plist` file but it still doesn't work.

So I tried to run the `HelloWorld` layer ( same project ). It has a `CCLabelTTF` with a `Thonburi` font. Worked fine on the iPad. But when I used `Thonburi` in my own layer, it didn't work! Why would it not be able to show a text with a `Thonburi` font in my own layer when it can in the `HelloWorld` layer?

The difference between the two `CCLabelTTF` objects are:

1. The `HelloWorld` version is a local variable while in my layer it is a member variable.
2. The `HelloWorld` version used `CCLabelTTF::create( text, font, size )` while in my layer I used `CCLabelTTF::create( text, dimension, alignment, font, size )`

Comment: Lance, I just posted a Question+Answer post on this question.  I had this same problem and was getting quite frustrated.  Because, though numerous users have had this problem, often times it was for various reasons.  My response is a combination of all solutions.  Follow my answer, and it should solve your problem.  If not, post a comment and I'll find the solution and update my answer.  Anyway, here is the post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508675/how-can-i-add-a-font-to-my-cocos2d-ios-project-and-use-it-with-a-cclabelttf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in 2.0, they change the API of the create function to create(const char *string, const char *fontName, float fontSize, const CCSize& dimensions, CCTextAlignment hAlignment)

Comment: The label does not show. 1. Yes, I have. It works fine on an iPhone. 2. False. I set it to be three times the font size. When I try to get the label's size, I get zero.

Comment: @LanceGray I copy your code into my project and I think I know why. in 2.0, they change the api to `create(const char *string, const char *fontName, float fontSize, const CCSize& dimensions, CCTextAlignment hAlignment)`

Comment: I tried it but it's not in the API. The only similar one is `CCLabelTTF::create(const char *string, const cocos2d::CCSize &dimensions, CCTextAlignment hAlignment, const char *fontName, float fontSize)` and that's what I am using.

Comment: @LanceGray That is wild, how about the label position? is it out of the screen?

Comment: It's still there. I don't know what the reason is but `CCLabelTTF` won't work. I've replaced my `CCLabelTTF` with `CCLabelBMFont` and I think the results were better than expected. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @LanceGray it is really strange, as long as it works fine on iphone, it is expected to work in ipad as well. sorry cannot help much.